# What can I do about the Japan Immigration policy on long term residents not getting a passport stamp?

Tags: visa, working, japan

If you live in Japan as a mid- to long-term visa holder with the latest visa about granted 1 year or earlier, then you know that the Japanese Immigration Bureau no longer stamps your passport with a sticker as they did before. Instead your status of residence is stated on your residence card along with its expiration date.

Unfortunately some employers have not changed their policies to allow for the change, so they need to see your passport, where no useful visa information is present. What can I do about this situation?

Comment: One possible solution: show your passport to your employer as you have been asked to do.

Comment: I have no problem showing it- it just just shows an expired visa.

Comment: As long as you have a newer alien card demonstrating that you are authorized to stay in Japan, the old expired visa should not be a problem, don't you think?

Comment: I have tried to fix the incorrect terminology, but I have no idea what "with the latest visa about 1 year ago" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I experienced something similar in another country. My solution was to print a screen dump from the governmental webpage that explained the rules and a print (verified or not) of my permit and fold it neatly into the passport and staple it to the last page. Employers and local authorities managed to deal with the conditions without having to ask me or loosing face. I don't know if it works in Japan, however.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to avoid companies with such incompetent idiots. Very common that they are incompetent not only in such small thing but in Japanese labour laws too. So you should expect demands for overtime more than it's allowed by laws because of pointless tasks and very inefficient and incompetent management.

Comment: This is Japan- government doesn't advertise at all so the head person doesn't know about the rules.